# How to automatically delete thousands of folders from the public_html folder?

Tags: php, ftp, cpanel

A friend of mine asked me to help cleaning her cPanel account because it got infected with malware. I logged in to cPanel and the built-in file manager crashed after a few minutes because this malware created 100.000s of folders and it couldn't even process it. Some of those are empty, the others are containing a few malicious PHP files. These folders names are just numbers (for example: 1979190). I tried to delete them through FTP but it's just not an option. My FTP client can only show 10.000 folders at a time. I tried to delete those but 2 hours later it's still deleting the folders with the first number sequence (1******) and the last folders are starting with number 9.

Unfortunately there's no SSH access for this account. I have contacted the support too but they won't help (they want us to pay $100 before they can run a single shell command...)

So my question is: What is the best way to delete all of those folders from the public_html directory? Is there a PHP script that could help? Maybe something that could delete all folders where the folder name is just numbers?

Any idea could help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: use the rmdir() php function to remove folders. unlink() to remove files.

Comment: In a PHP file you could try `exec('rm -rf /path/to/public_html/1*');` which will remove dirs starting with 1.  Then do `2*` etc..  THIS WILL REMOVE EVERYTHING.

Comment: I had this idea too but I'm pretty sure that the shell_exec is disabled on the server (it's from Hostgator). But I will give it a try soon. It would be great if I could just use this one.

Comment: You saved the day! I was able to delete those folders. This is the first time when I'm happy because of a vulnerable server. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use this script. It goes through the nested directories and remove them all.

```
<?php
  function rrmdir($dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
           rrmdir($dir."/".$object); 
        else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what I need. There's no more directory inside a directory, just thousands of single directories in the public_html folder. Most of them are empty, the others have 1, maybe 2 malicious PHP files in it. I just want to remove the 100.000+ number-named directories from the public_html but it's important to leave the site's files and folders intact. It's a WordPress site. Unfortunately I can't create a backup because there's no more free space on the account so I have to be careful before I start deleting everything with a script.

Comment: This scripts work for millions of files - if you want billions. If you don't want to delete some of folders, just add them to the `if` condition.